# Netty application stops working over time

Tags: java, http, netty

I have a http listener which is implemented using netty(4.1.5 Final). Its been running fine for almost 3 weeks before it stopped receiving data packets.The program didn't crash and no trivial error was found.

While going through the logs I came across the following error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/buffer/PoolArena$1
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.freeChunk(PoolArena.java:279)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache.freeEntry(PoolThreadCache.java:456)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:426)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:418)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:275)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:266)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free0(PoolThreadCache.java:239)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:235)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator$PoolThreadLocalCache.onRemoval(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:359)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator$PoolThreadLocalCache.onRemoval(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:345)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocal.remove(FastThreadLocal.java:226)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocal.removeAll(FastThreadLocal.java:67)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:146)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It had occurred 2 days before the application failed and also on the day it failed. By failed I mean it stopped receiving data packets.

I couldn't find many resources on this error.

Any idea what this error is or if this has something to do with the application's behaviour.

I am using netty 4.1.5 Final and java 7

Comment: Did you find any resolution ? I got this error when I killed the server

Comment: @sshntt I added a new dependency, and it's been running fine for more than a week now. Not sure if that's the fix.

    `<dependency>`
                `<groupId>io.netty</groupId>`
                `<artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>`
                `<version>4.1.5.Final</version>`
    `</dependency>`

Comment: Did you have netty-all included in your pom dependency previously ?

Comment: @sshntt Yes, ideally I think it should include netty-buffer too.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds either like a class loader issue or having multiple version of netty in the class path.

Comment: It's a mvn project and we have added only netty 4.1.5 in the pom.xml file.
Moreover, it ran fine for almost 3 weeks before encountering with this issue.